# Robot Framework - Convert JSON to dictionary

Tags: python, json, robotframework

I am having a problem converting a JSON file to a dictionary with Robot Framework.

```
*** Variables ***
${MY_DATA_TABLE VALUES}
${MY_JSON_FILE}    *path_to_JSON\test.json*


*** Keywords ***
Converting a JSON File
    ${MY_DATA_TABLE_VALUES_TEMP}   get file   ${MY_JSON_FILE}
    ${MY_DATA_TABLE_VALUES}    evaluate  json.loads('''${MY_DATA_TABLE_VALUES_TEMP}''')    json
    ${MY_DATA_TABLE_VALUES}=       convert to dictionary   ${MY_DATA_TABLE_VALUES}
    [Return]  ${MY_DATA_TABLE_VALUES}
```

I am under the impression that the json.loads function will return a string and not a dictionary and that is why I am trying to convert to a dictionary.

I intend to access the variable ${MY_DATA_TABLE_VALUES} in a few more RF keywords.

Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is the current result of the code you posted?

Comment: I dont think that the dictionary is loading into the variable. I think the variable remains blank (empty).

Comment: When I am trying to reference the variable, it thinks it is a string (from the json.loads code???). I am getting 'string indices must be integers, not unicode'

Comment: What's the value of the variable after the second line?

Comment: ${MY_DATA_TABLE_VALUES} = {u'username': u'ross.thomas@domainname.com', u'filename': u'Ross_Test_File_', u'filename_count': 1, u'campaign_name': u'Ross_Test_Campaign', u'password': u'password', u'campaign_count': 1}

Comment: That is from the log file

Comment: Then my first note would be that you need to un-unicode the values, and how to do that is a little beyond what I know at the moment.

Answer (score 6):

> I am under the impression that the json.loads function will return a string and not a dictionary

That is incorrect. It returns a dictionary. You do not need to call `convert to dict`, your code works fine without it.

Here's a working example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections

*** Variables ***
${MY_DATA_TABLE_VALUES_TEMP}  {"foo": "this is foo", "bar": "this is bar"}

*** Keywords ***
Converting a JSON File
    ${MY_DATA_TABLE_VALUES}    evaluate  json.loads($MY_DATA_TABLE_VALUES_TEMP)    json
    [Return]  ${MY_DATA_TABLE_VALUES}

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${data}=  converting a json file
    ${datatype}=  evaluate  str(type($data))
    should be equal  ${datatype}  <class 'dict'>
    should be equal  ${data['foo']}  this is foo
```